# Handling exponential numbers and formatting when exporting excel data via VBA to text file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue when exporting values (using VBA code, **not** via an export to CSV) from an Excel spreadsheet to a text file.

Using these numbers:

```
     -            (formatted so 0 displays as "-")
    0.10000000 
    0.0166666666666667 

If I debug.print the .Text then .Value property of each cell, the results are:
    -           --> 0
    0.10000000  --> 0.1
    0.01666667  --> 1.66666666666667E-02
```

My issue is, I want to avoid the 0.0166666666666667 (in the spreadsheet cell visually)  --> 1.66666666666667E-02 (in the cell's .Value property) conversion to happen.

If I read the .Text property instead, the result comes out as a decimal as desired, but the problem then is that the 0 formatted as "-" is exported as "-".

Is there a "proper" way to handle this that will work in **all** scenarios?
I have to use the final solution across multiple spreadsheets, and I have no control over the display format settings in each spreadsheet, or the contents of each cell (ie: not guaranteed to be numeric data)

### Example Code

```
Public Function test()
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim vSingle As Single
    Dim vVariant As Variant
    Dim vDouble As Double

    For i = 0 To 4
        vSingle = cell.Offset(i, 0).Value
        vVariant = cell.Offset(i, 0).Value
        vDouble = cell.Offset(i, 0).Value
        Debug.Print cell.Offset(i, 0).Text & " --> " & cell.Offset(i, 0).Value & " : " & vSingle & " : " & vVariant & " : " & vDouble
    Next
End Function
```

**Results in:**

```
                                          -  --> 0 : 0 : 0 : 0
0.10000000  --> 0.1 : 0.1 : 0.1 : 0.1
0.01666667  --> 1.66666666666667E-02 : 1.666667E-02 : 1.66666666666667E-02 : 1.66666666666667E-02
 -->  : 0 :  : 0
 -->  : 0 :  : 0
```

Comment: How are you exporting as text? Saving it as Csv retains the "0.01666667" format.

Comment: I am doing this programmatically using VBA.

Comment: You can save to csv programmatically as well. However you might want to share the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate your issue, but perhaps you can use the following code to help.  Basically, you can check if it's numeric, then store it into a strong-typed variable, and then export that.  You can use something like this:

```
Dim num As Double

Do
    If (IsNumeric(Selection.Value)) Then
        num = Selection.Value
        ' Export num
    Else
        ' Export Selection.Value
    End If
Loop Until True
```

Comment: I still can't replicate your error.  Your code works fine for me even if I have the cells formatted for different Number formats (the Single variable type outputs 0.0166667 as expected where the Variant shows 1.67E-02).  Is there a way you can provide an example workbook?

Comment: Very sorry, my example was incorrect.  I have updated it to 0.0166666666666667 which *should* now produce the effect I'm talking about?

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more elegant, but I think this is about as good as it gets.  Wrapping this in a function and calling that is probably the most realistic way to go.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'm not sure why it ends up in that format.  Maybe it's because of the output it ends up being formatted.  For example, maybe Debug.Print's immediate window can't handle that many characters so it has to use scientific notation.  If you store this in the spreadsheet maybe you can try Range.Formula = ... instead of Range.Value = ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Format` function to represent the value as you wnat

From Excel help

> > > Returns a Variant (String) containing an expression formatted according to instructions contained in a format expression.
> > >
> > > Format(expression[,format [,firstdayofweek [,firstweekofyear]]])

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in that I'm dealing with part catalogue numbers which can be string or number. My VBA code takes a value from an Excel source and assigns it into a Excel target template, processed by an application which inserts it into a table. The problem is that large "numbers" are converted into exponential notation. However, Acme Part# 847000003 <> Acme Part# 8.47E+08. My solution is to create a function that tests the input value, formats it as a general number and returns it as a forced string (with a prefixed apostrophe).

```
Public Function ConvertExponentialNumber(p_strCatalogueNbr As String) As String

Dim varTemp As Variant

If IsNumeric(p_strCatalogueNbr) Then

    varTemp = Format(p_strCatalogueNbr, "General Number")

    ConvertExponentialNumber = Chr(39) & varTemp

Else

    ConvertExponentialNumber = p_strCatalogueNbr

End If

End Function
```